# Letter over tilde in statistics

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am reading [Consequences and Detection of Misspecified Nonlinear Regression Models](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2287845). The letter A appears over the tilde relation which I have never seen before. What is does the A imply?

[image: Equation in question]

Comment: 'Asymptotically', probably.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right.